# Update With Another Column Max Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `states_risk`:

```
id | state | municipally | rating
```

example:

```
id | state | municipally | rating 
 1     AG     AG1            5
 2     AG     AG2            6
 3     AG     AG3            2
 4     AG     AG4            1
 5     AG     OTHER          -
 6     AB     AB1            0.2
 7     AB     AB2            2
 8     AB     AB3            10
 9     AB     OTHER          -
```

I need to update the value "rating" for `municipally = OTHER` set the `MAX(rating)` value by state "AG" - "AB", example: the id 5 set a 6 value from because is the max value for state AG.

Comment: Please avoid writing your title in all caps; it gives the impression you're yelling, and people won't want to help someone who is yelling at them.

Comment: ok, thanks you @TimLewis

Comment: No problem! So, for your question, have you tried writing any queries to try and solve this? What specific issue(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by joining the table to a query that returns the max rating for each state:

```
update states_risk s inner join (
  select state, max(rating) rating
  from states_risk
  group by state
) g on g.state = s.state
set s.rating = g.rating
where s.municipally = 'OTHER';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7e2xhVgB6KoPDUHEHktZRb/1).
Results:

```
| id  | state | municipally | rating |
| --- | ----- | ----------- | ------ |
| 1   | AG    | AG1         | 5      |
| 2   | AG    | AG2         | 6      |
| 3   | AG    | AG3         | 2      |
| 4   | AG    | AG4         | 1      |
| 5   | AG    | OTHER       | 6      |
| 6   | AB    | AB1         | 0.2    |
| 7   | AB    | AB2         | 2      |
| 8   | AB    | AB3         | 10     |
| 9   | AB    | OTHER       | 10     |
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the max values

```
 SELECT state, max(rating) as maxrating
 FROM states_risk
 GROUP BY state
```

This gives you the ones you want to update

```
 SELECT id, state
 FROM states_risk
 WHERE municiplally = 'OTHER'
```

So the update is

```
 UPDATE states_risk
 SET rating = (
   SELECT max(rating) as maxrating
   FROM states_risk inner
   WHERE inner.state = states_risk.state
 )
 WHERE municiplally = 'OTHER'
```

Answer (score 0):

If You column rating has '-' in his Column.
you need also to cast the column
Like

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version() |
> | :-------- |
> | 8.0.18    |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE states_risk
>     (`id` int, `state` varchar(2), `municipally` varchar(5), `rating` varchar(3))
> ;
> INSERT INTO states_risk
>     (`id`, `state`, `municipally`, `rating`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'AG', 'AG1', '5'),
>     (2, 'AG', 'AG2', '6'),
>     (3, 'AG', 'AG3', '2'),
>     (4, 'AG', 'AG4', '1'),
>     (5, 'AG', 'OTHER', '-'),
>     (6, 'AB', 'AB1', '0.2'),
>     (7, 'AB', 'AB2', '2'),
>     (8, 'AB', 'AB3', '10'),
>     (9, 'AB', 'OTHER', '-')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> Select * From states_risk;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | state | municipally | rating
> -: | :---- | :---------- | :-----
>  1 | AG    | AG1         | 5     
>  2 | AG    | AG2         | 6     
>  3 | AG    | AG3         | 2     
>  4 | AG    | AG4         | 1     
>  5 | AG    | OTHER       | -     
>  6 | AB    | AB1         | 0.2   
>  7 | AB    | AB2         | 2     
>  8 | AB    | AB3         | 10    
>  9 | AB    | OTHER       | -
> ```

> ```
> SELECT state, MAX(CAST(rating as FLOAT)) MAXrating 
>                               FROM states_risk WHERE rating <> '-' GROUP BY state
> ```
>
> ```
> state | MAXrating
> :---- | --------:
> AG    |         6
> AB    |        10
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE states_risk sr INNER JOIN (SELECT state, MAX(CAST(rating as FLOAT)) MAXrating 
>                               FROM states_risk WHERE rating <> '-' GROUP BY state) t1 
>                               ON sr.state = t1.state
> SET sr.rating = t1.MAXrating WHERE sr.municipally = 'OTHER';
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> Select * From states_risk;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | state | municipally | rating
> -: | :---- | :---------- | :-----
>  1 | AG    | AG1         | 5     
>  2 | AG    | AG2         | 6     
>  3 | AG    | AG3         | 2     
>  4 | AG    | AG4         | 1     
>  5 | AG    | OTHER       | 6     
>  6 | AB    | AB1         | 0.2   
>  7 | AB    | AB2         | 2     
>  8 | AB    | AB3         | 10    
>  9 | AB    | OTHER       | 10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4bc3c4296e3c26de028f55f45cae343)*